# How do I keep dining room chairs from being pulled over?

Tags: toddler, safety

I have a set of dining room chairs that do not have arms and, if pulled properly even when fully pushed in, can be pulled out onto the floor by my toddler.  A fact that I found out just today when I found him under one on the floor.

Obviously I do not want this to happen again - what can I do to prevent my toddler from pulling over the chair? Discouraging him from pulling them over already being something we frequently do.

For reference, our toddler is 21 months old, and can say many words but is only really just beginning to understand their meaning, so a sit-down-and-talk is also off the table.

Comment: Would it occur anyway if you positioned the chairs with their backs up against the wall? (21 months already???!!!)

Comment: @anongoodnurse Not really an option for this in our household unfortunately. (And yes my goodness the time has flown by).

Comment: Similar to what @anongoodnurse suggests, what if, when not in use, you stored them on their sides, pushed under the table as much as possible?

Comment: Putting them down on their sides under the table *might* work, though I worry that he may wind up rolling the chairs by pulling on the legs.

Comment: @Zibbobz A valid concern.  I thought is that a chair on its side will hurt less when it rolls over onto a toddler than an upright chair will when it falls.

Answer (score 4):

With children who are too young to be reasoned with, you either need to keep them away from the chairs, make it so the chairs cannot be pulled over, or notice and redirect when kiddo starts pulling them. If your dining room is totally separate, option one might work, as you can shut the door and keep them out of there. You could put the chairs up on the table so they can't reach them if you can't keep them away from the table. Otherwise, are they after something to push/climb? Can you redirect to something which is acceptable for them to push/climb on?

Comment: There's not a lot of safe options in our apartment for climbing, but there are a few I could try.  Unfortunately, there are no doors to close the dining room out, and even if we were to put the chairs up on the table, our son could just grab onto them and pull them down (which is even *more* dangerous).